# According to Preterism is the land mentioned in Ezekiel 37:25 "Heaven"?

Tags: eschatology, prophecy, israel, ezekiel, preterism

> NIV Ezekiel 37:
>
> 24 My servant David will be king over them, and they will all have
> one shepherd. They will follow my laws and be careful to keep my
> decrees. 25 **They will live in the land I gave to my servant Jacob, the
> land where your ancestors lived. They and their children and their
> children’s children will live there forever, and David my servant will
> be their prince forever.**

And are the "laws" the Torah?

Answer (score 1):

Preterist often see a spiritual fulfillment of Ezekiel 37. Preterist Don Preston writes;

> Paul, who preached nothing but the hope of Israel, wrote to the church at Corinth (comprised of members of the remnant of Israel) and he said, “you are the temple of God, as it is written” (my emphasis). He then quoted– verbatim!!– from Ezekiel 37:26! So, for Paul, Ezekiel 37 was being fulfilled in the body of Christ in the first century. It is prima facie false therefore, to claim that Ezekiel did not begin to be fulfilled until 1948.

https://donkpreston.com/was-the-restoration-of-israel-in-1948-prophetically-significant/

Comment: Okay, so is he saying that the land is still the land of Israel which was resurrected in the first century with John the baptizer, the messiah, the apostles and the saints as the new, spiritual temple in Jerusalem?

Comment: At the bottom of the page in the link, Preston says  "Paul cites that text verbatim and says that the church was that promised Temple / Tabernacle!" Preston sees the church and not the John the Baptist, etc. in the land of Israel as the temple. Jesus the apostles and saints could be included in that. That's the way I understand what he is saying.

Comment: He refers to the people as the temple (living stones) but is the temple in heaven or in the promised land?

Comment: I edited my reply. I would say wherever the church is, that's where the temple is. Check 2 Corinthians 6:14-16 and Ephesians 2:21. You would have to contact Preston for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but this is my interpretation.  I think this could be a prophecy about the forthcoming Messiah and the revival that comes through believing in Him and the life we live after accepting Him on earth that is to live an abundant life as if in Heaven but still on earth.

Comment: The question is about what Preterists believe. An appropriate answer to this question would involve citing Preterist writings that address this passage.

Comment: I think you expressed an opinion not so different from Preston above That shows insight.